# Unable to test SmtpClient.TimeOut

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I am using Visual Studio 2010, .NET 4.0 and I am trying to test the SMTPClient.TimeOut property and actually get it to throw a SmtpException. However, even when I set the TimeOut property to 1 millisecond, it still sends the email which seems like it is sending under a millisecond but what I find interesting is that when I inspect the object I can see a private member variable called timedOut set to true, indicating that it in fact timed out.

[image]

Here is my code:

```
try
{
            MailMessage emailMsg = new MailMessage(this.EmailFrom, this.EmailTo, this.EmailSubject, msg);
            //SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient(this.EmailServer);
            SmtpClient emailClient = new SmtpClient();
            emailClient.Credentials = new System.Net.NetworkCredential("username", "password");


                emailMsg.IsBodyHtml = true;
                emailClient.Timeout = Properties.Settings.Default.SMTPTimeOut;
                emailClient.Timeout = 1;

                emailClient.Send(emailMsg);
                sendingEmail = true;

            return sendingEmail;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
              // Handle time out exception here.
         }
```

Has anyone ever seen this or know a better way to test this? Right now I am hitting gmail's smtp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To finally test this was working I wrote a very simple TCP server console app on my local machine. I used the following tutorial on how to do this: http://bit.ly/XoHWPC

By creating this console app I was able to take my service which sends email and point it to my local machine (127.0.0.1,25).  The TCP Server console app accepted the connection but then I never send a response back.

My service sending the email successfully timed out as expected so I could finally verify it was working properly.  Here is a snippet of the TCP Server Console app from the tutorial for a guide. I recommend reading the whole tutorial though if you have time.

**Program.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace TCPServer
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Server server = new Server();
        }
    }
}
```

**Server.cs**

```
using System;
using System.Text;
using System.Net.Sockets;
using System.Threading;
using System.Net;

namespace TCPServer
{
    public class Server
    {

        private TcpListener tcpListener;
        private Thread listenThread;

        public Server()
        {
            this.tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 25);
            this.listenThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ListenForClients));
            this.listenThread.Start();
        }

        private void ListenForClients()
        {
            this.tcpListener.Start();

            while (true)
            {
                //blocks until a client has connected to the server
                TcpClient client = this.tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //create a thread to handle communication 
                //with connected client
                Thread clientThread = new Thread(new ParameterizedThreadStart(HandleClientComm));
                clientThread.Start(client);
            }
        }

        private void HandleClientComm(object client)
        {
            TcpClient tcpClient = (TcpClient)client;
            NetworkStream clientStream = tcpClient.GetStream();

            byte[] message = new byte[4096];
            int bytesRead;

            while (true)
            {
                bytesRead = 0;

                try
                {
                    //blocks until a client sends a message
                    bytesRead = clientStream.Read(message, 0, 4096);
                }
                catch
                {
                    //a socket error has occured
                    break;
                }

                if (bytesRead == 0)
                {
                    //the client has disconnected from the server
                    break;
                }

                //message has successfully been received
                ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(encoder.GetString(message, 0, bytesRead));
            }

            tcpClient.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does this prove? That no email gets sent ... because you don't send an email? A real server _does_ send the mail, so what happens is not what you want.

Comment: It proves that a connection was made to a server and the server doesn't reply back, there for a time out exception is thrown and the email was never sent which is exactly what I was wanting to test.

Answer (score 2):

I believe that you can use telnet. Turn on telnet and use that ip as your smtp server. It would not connect so it should timeout. Have not tested this.

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa995718(v=exchg.65).aspx

Comment: You didn't have to write your own server, you could have just used telnet built in windows as my answer stated. Oh well.

Comment: Scott your answer did help and I looked into the telnet which helped lead me to this. I wrote the server piece to step throw its code as well. I will up vote yours as helpful for sure.